# Angular + Spring boot REST, cannot post an entity with foreign key

Tags: json, angular, spring

I created a simple crud with Angular + Spring boot. I couldn't find a solution to solve my problem. I cannot post an entity with foreign key. I have two entities Product and Category.

**Category.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class ProductCategory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "category_name")
    private String categoryName;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "category")
    private Set<Product> products;

    public ProductCategory() {
    }

    public ProductCategory (Long id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }


    public Set<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }
}
```

**Product.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "brand")
    private String brand;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
    private ProductCategory category;


    public Product(Long id, String brand, String name, ProductCategory category) {
        this.id = id;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Product(){}

    public ProductCategory getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(ProductCategory category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Long getCategoryId() {
        return category.getId();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

When i save an entity via postman it works perfectly:

```
{
            "brand": "hp",
            "name": "envy",
            "category": {
                "id": 2
            }
        }
```

But when i post it in Angular i get an error in Spring/ Here is the stacktrace:

```
 org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.codejava.shoptest.entity.Product.category
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:721) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:707) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:554) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.codejava.shoptest.controller.ProductController.createProduct(ProductController.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Here is an error in dev tools in Chrome:

```
Angular is running in development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable production mode.
product-form.component.ts:44 Categories[{"id":1,"categoryName":"cellphones"},{"id":2,"categoryName":"laptops"}]
client:52 [WDS] Live Reloading enabled.

POST http://localhost:8080/products 500
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:2845
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:385
onScheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:272
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:378
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:210
scheduleMacroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:233
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone-evergreen.js:1134
(anonymous) @ zone-evergreen.js:2878
proto.<computed> @ zone-evergreen.js:1449
(anonymous) @ http.js:1776
_trySubscribe @ Observable.js:42
subscribe @ Observable.js:28
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:9
_innerSub @ mergeMap.js:59
_tryNext @ mergeMap.js:53
_next @ mergeMap.js:36
next @ Subscriber.js:49
(anonymous) @ subscribeToArray.js:3
_trySubscribe @ Observable.js:42
subscribe @ Observable.js:28
call @ mergeMap.js:21
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ filter.js:13
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ map.js:16
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
onSubmit @ product-form.component.ts:32
ProductFormComponent_Template_form_ngSubmit_2_listener @ product-form.component.html:3
executeListenerWithErrorHandling @ core.js:14316
wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault @ core.js:14351
schedulerFn @ core.js:24822
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:24791
onSubmit @ forms.js:4534
NgForm_submit_HostBindingHandler @ forms.js:4567
executeListenerWithErrorHandling @ core.js:14316
wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault @ core.js:14351
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:582
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:399
onInvokeTask @ core.js:27425
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:398
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:167
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:480
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1621
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1647
Show 19 more frames



ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/products", ok: false, …}error: error: "Internal Server Error"message: ""path: "/products"status: 500timestamp: "2020-09-05T09:15:57.997+00:00"__proto__: constructor: ƒ Object()hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()toString: ƒ ()valueOf: ƒ valueOf()__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}lazyInit: () => {…}arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 0name: ""__proto__: ƒ ()apply: ƒ apply()arguments: (...)bind: ƒ bind()call: ƒ call()caller: (...)constructor: ƒ Function()length: 0name: ""toString: ƒ toString()Symbol(Symbol.hasInstance): ƒ [Symbol.hasInstance]()get arguments: ƒ ()set arguments: ƒ ()get caller: ƒ ()set caller: ƒ ()__proto__: Object[[FunctionLocation]]: <unknown>[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0][[FunctionLocation]]: http.js:77[[Scopes]]: Scopes[4]lazyUpdate: nullnormalizedNames: Map(0)[[Entries]]No propertiessize: (...)__proto__: Map__proto__: Objectmessage: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/products: 500 OK"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 500statusText: "OK"url: "http://localhost:8080/products"__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

I suspect angular fails to parse category id into the database.

**How can i post such objects correctly? What is my mistake?**

Here is Angular code:

Product.ts

```
export class Product {
    id: string;
    brand: string;
    name: string;
    category: ProductCategory;
}
```

Product-category.ts

```
export class ProductCategory {
    id: number;
    categoryName: string;
}
```

Product-form.component.html

```
    <div class="card my-5">
    <div class="card-body">
      <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #productForm="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Brand</label>
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.brand" 
            class="form-control" 
            id="name" 
            name="name" 
            placeholder="Enter your name"
            required #name="ngModel">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Name</label>
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.name" 
            class="form-control" 
            id="name" 
            name="name" 
            placeholder="Enter your name"
            required #name="ngModel">
          <div [hidden]="!name.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">name is required</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="category">Category id</label>
          <select [(ngModel)]="product.category" name="category.id">
            <option *ngFor="let category of productCategories">{{ category.id }}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="!productForm.form.valid" 
          class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Product-form.component.ts

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from 'src/app/common/product';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/services/product.service';
import { ProductCategory } from 'src/app/common/product-category';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {


  product: Product;
  productCategories: ProductCategory[];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private productService: ProductService) {
      this.product = new Product();
     }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.listProductCategories();
  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.productService.save(this.product).subscribe(
      result => this.gotoProductList()
    );
  }

  gotoProductList(): void {
   this.router.navigate(['/products']);
  }

  listProductCategories() {
    this.productService.getProductCategories().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('Categories' + JSON.stringify(data));
        this.productCategories = data;
      }
    );

}
}
```

product.service.ts

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Product } from '../common/product';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ProductCategory } from '../common/product-category';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {
  

  private productsUrl: string;
  private categoryUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.productsUrl= 'http://localhost:8080/products';
    this.categoryUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/categories';
  }

  public findAll(): Observable<Product[]>{
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.productsUrl);
  }

  public save(product: Product){
    return this.http.post<Product>(this.productsUrl, product);
  }

  getProductCategories(): Observable<ProductCategory[]> {
   return this.http.get<ProductCategory[]>(this.categoryUrl);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your Product.ts file, you should declare Category as type Object, instead of number.

```
export class Product {
  id: string;
  brand: string;
  name: string;
  category : Object;
}
```

Then in html page, use a dropdown for selecting category, which will be a list of category objects (get this list using separate service call inside ngOnInit) and then while saving product object, make sure you set the category object inside the Product object.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I did like you said, but i have another exception. I edited my post and added new info there. Could you please have a look?

Comment: Not sure, but can you try adding one more constructor in your ProductCategory class with 2 arguments? public ProductCategory(int id, String name) { this.id = id; this.categoryName = name;
    }

Comment: May be somehow from angular, the 'id' of category is getting passed as string instead of integer/long as it expects at Java end. So, as you said it works in Postman because you are sending id as integer value ("category": {
                "id": 2
            }). You will have to debug ProductService Save() method and check if 'id' value of category is integer or string, before posting the request to Spring boot application. If it is string, then may be you need to change it to integer.

Comment: Thank you i edited my post and added errors from devtools in Chrome. Could you have a look please

Comment: i tried to add this log to my method: public save(product: Product){
  console.log(product.category.id);
    return this.http.post<Product>(this.productsUrl, product);
  }

Comment: But it gives me another error in devTools in chrome:   core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'categoryName' of undefined
    at ProductService.save (product.service.ts:27)

Comment: Thank you. Like you said angular parsed something ele. So i changed my input to: <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="product.category" name="category.id" /> it it started working. Didn't work with <select>

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you are sending this via postman your request body looks like this:

```
{
            "brand": "hp",
            "name": "envy",
            "category": {
                "id": 2
            }
        }
```

But via angular your body look like:

```
{
   "brand": "hp";
    "name": "envy";
    "category_id": 2;
}
```

I advice you to change your Product class structure. Category field exactly.

You must pay big attention to what your rest api is expecting and what you are really sending. Always try to compare values what you are sending via postman and browser. In browser you can check this in chrome dev tools -> network.

You can adjust your frontend to your backend or vice versa. If you would like change backend rather that frontend read about DTO.

Comment: thank you for your help! I changed my code but i have another exception. I edited this post could you hava a look?

Comment: @JohnSmithJohn change to `category: ProductCategory ` in Product  and will work

Comment: I tried so but it doesn't work either. Then i changed it to Object like "sandeepkondhare" advised. What is my mistake?

Comment: I would stay with my suggestion. What error you are getting then?

Comment: When i changed it like this: "category: ProductCategory". I get the same error: " PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.codejava.shoptest.entity.Product.category"

Comment: Can you show what json is sending your angular app. You can check this in network overlap in network dev tools.

Comment: I edited my post and added errors from devtools in Chrome. Could you please have a look?

Comment: Try `@JoinColumn(name = "category", nullable = false)`. Have you these categories in database? I mean do you have already categories with id 1 and 2 in your database?

Comment: i have this code: @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false). Yes, these categories are in the db

Comment: Try just category not caregory_id, because in your request body you have category var. or read about DTO.

Comment: if it works in postman i think the problem is with angular code. With html code or product.service.ts in particular. I suppose it fails to parse category. Maybe it's like this

Comment: I changed like you said to "category" it stopped toshow categories at all in Nagular. But somehow i managed to solve my issue. I changed input to this:  <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="product.category" name="category.id" /> and it started to work. Didn't work with <selecct>

Answer (score 0):

I always use `Data Transfer Object` pattern to hold the data from the frontend and convert it to your JPA Entities before saving into the database.

My example:

[PostForm](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-microservice-sample/blob/master/post-service/src/main/java/com/hantsylabs/sample/springmicroservice/post/PostForm.java) is used to accept the data from the user input form.

In [PostController](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-microservice-sample/blob/master/post-service/src/main/java/com/hantsylabs/sample/springmicroservice/post/PostController.java#L74-L90), called `PostService`,  I used the service to [convert it to JPA entity `Post`](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-microservice-sample/blob/master/post-service/src/main/java/com/hantsylabs/sample/springmicroservice/post/PostService.java#L29-L39).

The frontend codes for this api is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/angular2-material-sample/), it is also written in Angular 2(a little old).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i'm new to Angular so it was hard for me to understand you solution. I changed my code and got another mistake, could you hava a look at my post again. I edited it. Thanks'

Comment: Your API is problematic. If you do not write [testing codes](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-microservice-sample/tree/master/post-service/src/test/java/com/hantsylabs/sample/springmicroservice/post), try to use `curl` or Postman to verify your APIs before serving frontend.

Comment: I used postman. When i post it via postman it works. But doesn't work from Angular. Taht was my issue